# Thoughts on type aliases/synonyms?

Tags: programming-languages

I'm going to try my best to frame this question in a way that doesn't result in a language war or list, because I think there could be a good, technical answer to this question.

Different languages support type aliases to varying degrees. C# allows type aliases to be declared at the beginning of each code file, and they're valid only throughout that file. Languages like ML/Haskell use type aliases probably as much as they use type definitions. C/C++ are sort of a Wild West, with `typedef` and `#define` often being used seemingly interchangeably to alias types.

The upsides of type aliasing don't invoke too much dispute:

- It makes it convenient to define composite types that are described naturally by the language, e.g. `type Coordinate = float * float` or `type String = [Char]`.
- Long names can be shortened: `using DSBA = System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepBoundaryAttribute`.
- In languages like ML or Haskell, where function parameters often don't have names, type aliases provide a semblance of self-documentation.

The downside is a bit more iffy: aliases can proliferate, making it difficult to read and understand code or to learn a platform. The Win32 API is a good example, with its `DWORD = int` and its `HINSTANCE = HANDLE = void*` and its `LPHANDLE = HANDLE FAR*` and such. In all of these cases it hardly makes any sense to distinguish between a HANDLE and a void pointer or a DWORD and an integer etc..

Setting aside the philosophical debate of whether a king should give complete freedom to their subjects and let them be responsible for themselves or whether they should have all of their questionable actions intervened, could there be a happy medium that would allow the benefits of type aliasing while mitigating the risk of its abuse?

As an example, the issue of long names can be solved by good autocomplete features. Visual Studio 2010 for instance will alllow you to type DSBA in order to refer Intellisense to System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepBoundaryAttribute. Could there be other features that would provide the other benefits of type aliasing more safely?

Comment: Intellisense or not, System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepBoundaryAttribute is much less readable in code than DSBA, especially when used often.

Comment: @zvrba: actually, `DebuggerStepBoundaryAttribute` is much *more* readable than `DSBA`. In the first case, you know what does it mean. In the second one, you have no idea. Now imagine you use twenty different aliases like this in code. Would anyone have enough courage to try to read and understand your code?

Answer (score 3):

Two features come to my mind:

**Portability.** In languages like C, where datatypes like `int` are platform specific, an alias like `DWORD` makes it easier to ensure you are really using a 32bit signed integer everywhere, when this is the requirement for your program, even when you port the program to a plattform where `int` is e.g. 16bit unsigned and therefore `DWORD` has to be an alias for `signed long`.

**Abstraction.** In your program, you might use a lot of integer and floating point numbers for different purposes. By creating aliases like `SPEED`, `HEIGHT`, `TEMPERATURE`, it's relatively easy to change one of those e.g. from `float` to `double` and leave the others as they are.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question though...

Comment: @Rei, you are right that ammoQ did not answer the question but really commented on it. Nevertheless, P.SE does not allow formatted or long comments... I think he doesn't deserve a downvote: his comment is on topic and a good one.

Comment: @Andrea it doesn't seem to be the result of having read the question in its entirety; aside from the note on portability (which is just another item to put in list of upsides), it's just a restatement.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Andrea you need encapsulation, however I disagree that this needs to be expensive.

I think the Happy medium would be type safe typedefs, probably allowing explicit conversion between the real type and the typedef, but preventing implict conversion.

i.e. the main problem I see with typedefs in alot of languages is they do not actually introduce a new type but simply an alias, while this is useful, it is not as useful as a new type which is like the old type but with a new name.  And composition or inheritance are too heavy if you only want to ensure you don't mix a couple of variables.

Comment: I could not agree more, I would really like to see this kind of "limited" polymorphism. If `type Name = String`, then a `String` cannot be passed to a function expected a `Name`, but the reverse is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think type aliases give the lazy programmer (very) cheap encapsulation. So maybe the alternative could be just to use proper (expensive) encapsulation.

There is also the argument that the former is also much more optimized for the machine / language in use than the latter, though.